# why substraction result is wrong ? assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

```
section .data 

  intArray  dw 100,90,80,70,60

   twoNums db '   %d  %d  ',0,10

num dw 10
numIs db '   %d  ',10,0


hello : db 'hello',10,0


section .text 


global main 
extern printf 


main : 


mov ebx,intArray

mov esi,0



arrayTravel:

movzx eax,word[intArray+esi]

movzx ebx,word[intArray+esi+2]



push ebx

push eax

push twoNums

call printf

add esp,12



sub eax,ebx

push eax

push numIs

call printf

add esp,8   



ret
```

result should be  10   instead   i t giving -78

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `printf` it returns the number of characters printed in `EAX`, in this case 12. Subtract 90 from that and you get -78.

You cannot assume that the functions you call wouldn't change the values in registers, especially `EAX`, you must preserve them. The calling convention will define which registers are preserved and which are not.

Comment: thanks  i replaced  add esp,12   with   add esp,4    then used pop for both regs.  working fine.    thanks a lot.

Comment: @matheromqq whilst your fix may work in this case it will not do so generally.  Here the function parameters (being passed by value) are copied to the stack for passing to the function. However, unless the calling convention says otherwise, the called function is entitled to modify these copies.  You must therefore preserve the values in a place the calling function controls.  e.g, a (preserved) register, the stack, memory etc.  On the other hand, if you assume, as you appear to be being doing, that no registers are preserved you are making life much harder for yourself!